# adding a file/styles/extention in phpBB from azure gallery

Tags: azure, phpbb3

i'm new to azure, and just deploying phpBB from the app gallery
is there any way to add new styles/extention to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the Gallery, you are just creating a web service and automatically uploading whatever software into that service.

To modify your web app, you can FTP into it. First, you need to create an FTP login:

- In the blade for your web app, click All settings:
- Click Deployment credentials.
- Enter a user name and password.
- Click Save.

The full FTP user name is “app\username” where app is the name of your web app. The username is listed in the web app blade, under Essentials.

Then follow this phpBB guide for installing styles: https://www.phpbb.com/support/docs/en/3.1/kb/article/how-to-install-styles-on-phpbb3/

When it comes to the FTP steps, use the info you see on your web app and the login you just created.

Extensions are installed a similar way.

Alternatively, you could also set up a git repo with a copy phpbb in it, then push that repo onto your web app. But that is more complicated, FTP is your most direct bet to modifying your phpBB web app.

Comment: and there's button for downloading the publishSetting in the azure manager, it contains all the user id password needed in plain text (i don't know its a features or a flaw btw). Thanks